# How to enter text into user name when user name text field is on different frame using Webdirver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have to login to application. But username and password text boxes available on different frame on the UI.

When i record using the IDE and exported into JAVA then same  code is not working.
I am getting an error saying element is not present. This because the text box is on additional frame on the UI.

Kindly let me how to get the control of this frame and then enter the text.

Thanks,
Md Ashfaq

Comment: How about you show some research into the matter, when asking questions? Takes less than a minute to Google this up: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#moving-between-windows-and-frames

Answer (score 0):

are you recording via ide on firefox and then running your tests on some other browser?coz sometimes diff browsers interpret it differently[I have faced issues where same webpage had iframes in firefox but not in IE].kindly check on that front.

Answer (score 0):

Use The API capability to SwitchToFrame() then Look for element and interact with.
Note: You'll have to switch to any frame needed i find it efficient doing a selectDefaultFrame, try Iterating within Available frames and get handle/frame names